# TIMESTAMPDIFF Missing Days

Tags: sql, db2, timestampdiff

Can someone explain to me why this returns only 360 days and not 365 days?

I expect it to not count the first day but, what about the other 4 days?

```
SELECT
(TIMESTAMPDIFF(16,CHAR(TIMESTAMP('2017-12-31') - TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01'))))
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

I am planning on just adding + 5 at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have DB2 for Linux, Unix and Windows - now called Db2 - Version 11.1 you could also use

```
SELECT DAYS_between('2017-12-31','2017-01-01') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: That is very nice! Can I ask where you found this function at?

Comment: It is all in the documentation - IBM Knowledge Center - specially the built-in functions can save you lots of work:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011043.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000861.html) explains this pretty well:

> The returned estimate may vary by a number of days. For example, if
>   the number of days (interval 16) is requested for the difference
>   between '1997-03-01-00.00.00' and '1997-02-01-00.00.00', the result is
>   30. This is because the difference between the timestamps is 1 month, and the assumption of 30 days in a month applies.

In other words, the difference is 11 months and 30 days -- 11 * 30 + 30 = 360.

```
SELECT DAYS(DATE('2017-12-31')) - DAYS(DATE('2017-01-01'))
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

For a more exact representation, try: